# Reading MacOs Environment Variables in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, macos, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am trying to set some API credentials in the Spring boot property file "application.property" using environment variables. My environment variables look as such:

```
export ACCOUNT_SID ="some value"
export AUTH_TOKEN="some value"
```

Now when I run echo command I get the "some value" for each variable and even when I run a System.getenv("ACCOUNT_SID") in a regular java application. However, when I set the values in the property file, all I get is the strings "${ACCOUNT_SID}" and "${AUTH_TOKEN}" injected into my POJO fields. i.e assume the following configuration in my application.property file:

```
twilio.account_sid=${ACCOUNT_SID}
twilio.auth_token=${AUTH_TOKEN}
```

Where ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN are my environment variables. Next I set my POJO as such:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="twilio")
public class TwilioConfig {
    private String accountSid;
    private String authToken;

    geters/setters
}
```

When I run this and try to print the values of the fields I get ${ACCOUNT_SID} and ${AUTH_TOKEN} printed in the console. The main java file looks as such.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmshotlineApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private TwilioConfig twilio;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("ACCOUNT_SID="+twilio.getAccountSid());
        System.out.println("ACCOUNT_SID="+twilio.getAuthToken());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmshotlineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

I even try injecting the value by using @Value annotation on variables. When I tested using JAVA_HOME environment variable, I actually got to print the path but when I try to do the same with my defined environment variables, the program crashed because the values could not be found. So I had to give a default value which is what gets printed. example below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmshotlineApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${java.home}")
    String javaHome;
    @Value("${account.sid:DEFAULT}")
    String ACCOUNT_SID;
    @Value("${auth.token:DEFAULT}")
    String AUTH_TOKEN;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("ACCOUNT_SID="+ACCOUNT_SID);
        System.out.println("ACCOUNT_SID="+AUTH_TOKEN);
        System.out.println("JAVA_HOME="+javaHome);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmshotlineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Please help me understand or see what am I doing wrong. If the variables are not being seen by the program, makes me think that I am setting the environment variables wrongly. But at the same time this confuses me because when I use System.getenv() in a regular(not spring boot Java) program, I get to print the values! I am using Mac OS Catalina and my env var are store in my profile file ~/.profile.

Comment: In your question, you say `API_SID` but also `ACCOUNT_SID`.

Comment: sorry, that was just example. It should have been ACCOUNT_SID. i will try to edit it.

Comment: Don't inject them to the `SpringBootApplication` class. Create a different one, fairly sure this is too early in lifecycle for them to be injected. Also you're missing the point of the `TwilioConfig ` class. Inject the `TwilioConfig ` as a spring bean and use the getters/setters/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am very new to Spring framework and Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment properties on ~/.bash_profile.
If you are running your app with IntelliJ you can verify the system properties that are included by opening 'Edit Run/Debug configuration' dialog -> Configuration -> Environment Variables -> Click on Browse -> Check Include System Environment Variables (and verify if your variables are in there, if not your environment properties were not included)

[Verify in your Intellij Run/debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKjwW.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

The first thing is you should not call the properties in `SpringBootApplication` class, but you should use `@Value` from other kind of context. In addition for reading your properties configs from `application.properties`  by using `@Value` then you should call the property with the same name, I reviewed your code but you are not calling the same property name, for example:

application.properties

```
twilio.account_sid=${ACCOUNT_SID}
twilio.auth_token=${AUTH_TOKEN}
```

SmsHotLineApplication class

```
@Value("${twilio.account_sid:DEFAULT}")
String ACCOUNT_SID;
@Value("${twilio.auth_token:DEFAULT}")
String AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Then should work, if you want to use the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="twilio")` 
Then you should call the same how you named your properties, for example:

application.properties

```
twilio.accountSid=${ACCOUNT_SID}
twilio.authToken=${AUTH_TOKEN}
```

TwilioConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="twilio")
public class TwilioConfig {
    private String accountSid;
    private String authToken;

    geters/setters
}
```

Comment: When I use the @Value like you suggested my program crashes and When I use the same name as in the application.properties file the program still prints "${ACCOUNT_SID}" and  "${AUTH_TOKEN}". The reason I use, and correct me if I'm wrong, the @Value("${account.sid:DEFAULT}") was to access my environment variable directly just as I did with @Value("${java.home}") where java.home maps JAVA_HOME and account.sid maps ACCOUNT_SID

Comment: Those are wrong, when you use `export ....` on command you just set up on terminal, what IDE are you using? You should add your environment  variables into your OS. that is the problem...

Comment: Take a look this https://medium.com/@youngstone89/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I was looking on how to set environment variables in Mac OS and that's what I found. I thought that might be the problem. Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: Yes, @LeoR I updated my answer, you can check the firs paragraph which mentions you should call `@Value` on a service, or other type of class, instead of use in `SpringBootApplicaton` class.